# Save in txt files locally using chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a simple chrome extension to hide magic cards that I don't want to see in store searchs.  everything is working fine, except for persisting data. I don't want to retrieve a server, just made the extension save the blocked cards locally in a txt file with names, but I couldn't find a way to do that, anyone knows how?
This is the code I'm trying to write, the "appendName" function should be the responsible to save the names:

```
function appendName(cardName, fileName) {
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
}
  

// Function to handle button clicks
function handleButtonClick(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
    appendName(event.target.id, "list.txt");
  }
  
// Find all button elements on the page
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.block-button');

// Attach the click event listener to each button
buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick);
});
```

If chrome API really don`t allow that, is there a way to make it work locally without beeing complicated for commom users?

I've tried some codes that can open the download window from the browser, and it worked, but it is so slow to use that doesnt make sense.

Comment: Extensions have [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/), can you use it instead?

Comment: Chrome storage have worked, I've totally forgot of this, thank you!